# Permission Denied error while building gcc in PythonAnyWhere

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to build the `gcc-7.4.0` in PythonAnyWhere. I downloaded the `gcc-7.4.0` via `wget` and I ran the following commands successfully.

```
~ $ mkdir gccbuild

~ $ cd gccbuild

~/gccbuild $ ../gcc-7.4.0/configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-7.4.0 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran 
--disable-multilib --program-suffix=-7.4

~/gccbuild $ make -j 8
```

Now I'm trying to run the `make install-strip` command but it gives a `Permission denied` error such as below.

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sfmyazilim/gccbuild'
/bin/bash ../gcc-7.4.0/mkinstalldirs /usr/local/gcc-7.4.0 /usr/local/gcc-7.4.0
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/gcc-7.4.0 /usr/local/gcc-7.4.0
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/gcc-7.4.0’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/gcc-7.4.0’: Permission denied
Makefile:2581: recipe for target 'installdirs' failed
make[1]: *** [installdirs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sfmyazilim/gccbuild'
Makefile:2491: recipe for target 'install-strip' failed
make: *** [install-strip] Error 2
```

I cannot use `sudo` because PythonAnyWhere doesn't allow it. How can I install the built GCC via the `make install-strip` command without any errors?

Comment: You need to build it in your home directory, not system-wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the `configure` command, you can set the directory for installation with the `--prefix` flag, so you need to add on something like `--prefix=$HOME/.local` to that so that it will install to your home directory's `.local` subdirectory, which is the standard place for user-specific binaries like this.  So you should go through the process again, configuring with that additional parameter, making the binaries with the `make -j 8` command, and then run the `make install` step.